# cxf:proxy-client [java.lang.Exception: No such operation]

Tags: mule

I am getting No Such Operation exception when I try to consume a web service as CXF proxy client.Am I not configuring CXF proxy client correctly? I'll appreciate any feedback.

My flow and exception detail is mentioned below.

```
<flow name="XML121Order">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="mviq.121.order" />
    <outbound-endpoint address="https://www.example.com/appsacord/acordwebs.asmx" 
                       exchange-pattern="request-response" >
        <cxf:proxy-client operation="AppsAcord" 
                          payload="body" 
                          enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" />
    </outbound-endpoint>

    <xm:object-to-xml-transformer />

    <logger message="File payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" />

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/eip/mvi/output" 
                            outputPattern="apps_xml121-[function:dateStamp]" />
</flow>
```

Exception stack is:

1. No such operation: AppsAcord (java.lang.Exception)
   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:279 (null)
2. No such operation: AppsAcord (java.lang.Exception) (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:141 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)

---

Root Exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: No such operation: AppsAcord
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:279)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:360)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:200)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:127)
    at org.mule.endpoint.outbound.OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.process(OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.java:39)
    at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:49)
    at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:46)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:116)
    at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultOutboundEndpoint.process(DefaultOutboundEndpoint.java:96)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:164)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:309)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If I mention payload="envelope" instead of "body"and create soap envelope by hand, it works. So, I suspect the problem is due to the namespace. I don't know how to mention namespace in <cxf:proxy>. Anyone knows how to set namespace for proxy client?

Comment: Any time you have a problem with namespaces it get usually solved by adding namespace-manager to your mule config. You can find the doc here http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/XML+Namespaces

Comment: I do have the namespace manager declared in my config and using it in XPATH expression. But I haven't figured out how I can use that in   `<cxf:proxy-client operation="AppsAcord" 
                          payload="body" 
                          enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" />`. The objective is still to get rid of **No such operation** exception. Also I observed that if I remove **operation** attribute altogether, the proxy client works, but I have NO control on which operation (out of 4 declared in WSDL) will it invoke. Still confused and needing help :-) **Is this a Mule BUG????**

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. What payload do you receive over JMS? Is it a full SOAP envelope or just a SOAP body or something else?

Comment: I receive XML over JMS. This XML is the payload for the webservice call. It's my understanding that if I mention the operation name and state payload as body (in cxf:proxy-client attributes), mule should create a soap envelope and insert the body(XML received over JMS) into that envelope under the stated operation.